# Daily Sales Data - Week Days Only, No Holidays

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I'm trying to predict the daily sales for a take out restaurant. They are located in the downtown core of a large city. Their primary customers are office workers on their lunch breaks, and as such they are only open on business days. No weekends or holidays.

I would like to (possibly) use Holt-Winters triple exponential smoothing to forecast sales a few months into the future - using about four years of daily sales data. There are clear seasonal patterns (less busy in the summer months, for example, when many office workers are on vacation).

How can I account for no weekend sales and holidays that may change dates from year to year? I've noticed that if Monday is a holiday, the Friday preceding that long weekend has noticeably lower sales (presumably from people skipping lunch and starting the weekend early).

I'm using R to perform my analysis. Any input would be appreciated in terms of dealing with the changing holidays and choosing a proper model.